# Presentation of ValidationProblemDetails with own ProblemDetailsFactory

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am currently learning the development with asp .net core apis (5.0). For the sake of learning, I implemented an own ProblemFactory class to display the ValidationProblemDetails in another way (I just displayed the details message with some content I wanted to have there). As exception handler I use a Controller with path /error. So far so good. Now I would like to remove the errors-Property from the ValidationProblemDetails class, which seems to be not possible. The erros property has no setter and if you initialise that property from the constructor with null, there will be an argumentException thrown by the constructor. Is there a way to customize the output in a way, that the property will be removed from the output? Can I catch that ValidationProblemDetails somewhere in the pipeline and map it to another output object?

Answer (score 0):

> Now I would like to remove the errors-Property from the
> ValidationProblemDetails class, which seems to be not possible.

I also think errors property cannot be removed or set.You can try to use `ProblemDetails`.ProblemDetails has all the properties of ValidationProblemDetails except Errors.
Here is the properties of ProblemDetails:
[image]

And here is the properties of ValidationProblemDetails:
[image]